# Listen to more than one KeyphraseSearch

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I have been creating an Android app which works fine when it is listening to one KeyPhrase with following config:

```
private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
private static final String KEYPHRASE = "oh mighty computer";

    recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
            .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
            .setKeywordThreshold(1e-20f)
            .getRecognizer();

    recognizer.addListener(this);

    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
```

How can I add a second keyphrase which is recognized too?
I tried the following:

```
private static final String KWS_SEARCH2 = "up";
private static final String KEYPHRASE2 = "hello my name is";

recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH2, KEYPHRASE2);

@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis == null)
        return;

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();

    if (text.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
        restartRecognizer(KWS_SEARCH);
    else if (text.equals(KWS_SEARCH2))
        restartRecognizer(KWS_SEARCH2);
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?  What did you expect instead?  Be as detailed as possible, not just "it didn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the file in assets with keyphrase list of the following form (one per-line with the following threshold):

```
 oh mighty computer /1e-40/
 hello my name is /1e-38/
```

and create a search with `addKeywordSearch` which loads a file instead of `addKeyphraseSearch`.